# как применить свойства кнопок к другим фоткам?

Tags: html, css

Здраствуйте, идея была следующая, сверстать полностью плеер для одной картинки и затем копируя и меняя название перенести для следующих картинок, но проблема оказалась в том, что я использовал position и подгонять его к каждой картинке муторно, да и скорее всего не совсем правильно, **вопрос таков**, *можно ли с помощью флексов сделать также?* и еще парочку вопросов про верстку, если внимательно посмотреть, то видно, что кнопки next - play -  next прыгают, хотя заданы одинаковые параметры к ним, как исправить(1)? также у меня блок самого плеера куда отступил вверх, тоже не понимаю как это можно исправить(2), и вопрос последний, как сделать, чтобы ползунок таймера трека можно было двигать или хотя бы нажимать на определенное место полоски и чтобы ползунок перемещался туда(3). также для удобства я пронумеровал свои вопросы и нумерацию перенесу на скрин. заранее огромное спасибо!!!

```css
/* стили гугл */
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@300;400&family=Staatliches&display=swap');

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@600;700&display=swap');

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Indie+Flower&display=swap');


* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;

}

/* начало - менюшки */
/* header img{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-start;
    padding: 0px;
    

    position: absolute;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    left: 20px;
    top: 40px;
} */
/* конец - менюшки */


/* начало левый бар с ссылками */

/* начало кнопки - музыка */

.music_platina {
    position: absolute;
    top: -80px;

}

.music_platina a {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    line-height: 1.2;
}


/* конец кнопки - музыка */

.left_bar_social {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-start;
    padding: 0px;

    position: absolute;
    left: 40px;
    top: 120px;
}

.left_bar_social img {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 70px;
}

/* начало концерты */

.concert_artist a {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    line-height: 1.2;
    color: black;

    padding-top: 0px;
}

/* конец концерты  */

/* конец - левый бар с ссылками */



.wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    aspect-ratio: 3 / 2;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, #9e9e9e 0%, #ffffff 30%, #6a6a6a 100%);
}

/* надпись - имя, дата */
.info_artist {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-start;
    padding: 0px;

    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(transparent, transparent), url(https://thumbs.gfycat.com/ReadyFarawayLeopard-size_restricted.gif) repeat;
    background: -o-linear-gradient(transparent, transparent);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;

    position: absolute;
    width: 812px;
    height: 258px;
    left: 160px;
    top: 100px;
}

.name_artist {
    width: 394px;
    height: 95px;


    font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 60px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

/* .date_concert_artist {
    width: 334px;
    height: 91px;

    font-family: 'Circular Std';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 35px;
    line-height: 40px;
} */

/* конец - надпись имя, дата */


/* начало - скрины треков */
.cards {
    position: absolute;
    width: 135%;
    text-align: center;
    transform: translateX(29%) translateY(-25%) rotateX(50deg) rotateZ(330deg) skewX(19deg) skewY(350deg);
}

.cards img {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 88%;
    border-radius: 30px;
    padding-top: 50px;

}

.cards>* {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20%;
    aspect-ratio: 1 / 2;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    border-radius: 30px;
}

.cards>*:nth-child(1) {
    background: linear-gradient(0deg, #000000 0%, #000000 0%, #42353c 50%);
}

.cards>*:nth-child(2) {
    background: linear-gradient(0deg, #000000 0%, #000000 0%, #382239 50%);
}

.cards>*:nth-child(3) {
    background: linear-gradient(0deg, #000000 0%, #000000 0%, #312829 50%);
}

.cards>*:nth-child(4) {
    background: linear-gradient(0deg, #000000 0%, #000000 0%, #382239 50%);
}

.cards>*:nth-child(5) {
    background: linear-gradient(0deg, #000000 0%, #000000 40%, #3f2722 50%);
}

.cards>*:nth-child(6) {
    background: linear-gradient(0deg, #000000 0%, #000000 0%, #331f21 100%);
}

.cards>*:nth-child(7) {
    background: linear-gradient(0deg, #000000 0%, #000000 40%, #3f2722 100%);
}

.cards>*:nth-child(8) {
    background: linear-gradient(0deg, #000000 0%, #000000 40%, #3f2722 100%);
}


/* .cards img>*:nth-child(7) {
    background: linear-gradient(0deg, #000000 0%, #000000 40%, #3f2722 100%);
 }

 .cards img>*:nth-child(8) {
    background: linear-gradient(0deg, #000000 0%, #000000 40%, #3f2722 100%);
 } */

/* конец - скрины треков */


@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Meera+Inimai&display=swap');
/*шрифт для название песни */

/* начало - верстка самого плеера */

.name_container {
    position: absolute;
    left: 200px;
    top: 410px;
}

.track {
    font-family: 'Meera Inimai', sans-serif;
    font-size: 19px;
    color: #f6eef3;
}

.artist {
    font-family: 'Meera Inimai', sans-serif;
    font-size: 19px;
    color: #a99ba6;
}

/* начало - прогресс бар */
.progress_bar {
    position: relative;
    top: 105px;
    left: 30px;
    width: 330px;
    height: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.progress_bar::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    right: 315px;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 4px rgba(46, 45, 45, 1));
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.progress_bar::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    width: 100%;
    height: 5px;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .3);
    border-radius: 5px;
    z-index: -1;
}


/* конец - прогресс бар */

/* начало - тайминги */
.time_bar {
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    top: 515px;
    left: 190px;
    color: #a99ba6;
}

.start_track {
    font-family: 'Meera Inimai', sans-serif;
    position: absolute;
    left: 5px;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.end_track {
    font-family: 'Meera Inimai', sans-serif;
    position: absolute;
    left: 300px;
    font-size: 16px
}

/* конец - тайминги */

/* начало панели переключение */

.panel_players {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    top: 165px;
    margin: 0;
}

.left_button img {
    padding: 20px;
    max-width: 50px;
}

.play_button img {
    max-width: 50px;
    padding: 20px;
}

.rigth_button img {
    max-width: 50px;
    padding: 20px;
}


/* конец панели переключение */

/*  старт - громкость */

.panel_volume {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    top: 200px;
    justify-content: center;
}

input[type="range"] {
    display: block;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    background-color: #bdc3c7;
    width: 250px;
    height: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    outline: 0;
}

input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    background-color: #303331;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 2px solid white;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: .4s ease-in-out;
}

​ input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb:hover {
    background-color: #000000;
}

input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb:active {
    transform: scale(1.6);
}

/* конец - громкость */

.volume_regulator{
    width: 50px;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    top: 135px;
    justify-content: center;
}

.rigth_volume {
    position: relative;
    left: 310px;
}

.left_volume{
    position: relative;
    left: 25px;
    top: 5px;
}

/* конец - верстка самого плеера */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <title>Платина</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <!-- <header>
            <img src="img/b/b_bedolaga.png" alt="">
        </header> -->


        <div class="left_bar_social">
            <div class="music_platina">
                <a href="#">МУЗЫКА</a>
            </div>

            <a href="https://vk.com/platinarnbklub" target="_blank"><img src="img/social/vk.png" alt="vk"></a>
            <a href="https://www.instagram.com/platina300/?hl=ru" target="_blank"><img src="img/social/insta.png" alt="insta"></a>
            <a href="https://www.youtube.com/c/%D0%9F%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0300" target="_blank"><img src="img/social/youtube.png" alt="youtube"></a>
            <a href="https://t.me/sosamuzik300" target="_blank"><img src="img/social/telegram.png" alt="telegram"></a>
            <a href="https://music.apple.com/ru/artist/%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0/1309211809" target="_blank"><img src="img/social/apple_music.png" alt="apple music"></a>

            <div class="concert_artist">
                <a target="_blank" href="concert_platina/concert_platina.html">КОНЦЕРТЫ</a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="info_artist">
                <div class="name_artist">
                    <p>ПЛАТИНА</p>
                </div>

                <!-- <div class="date_concert_artist">
                    <p>16.10.2022 MOSCOW</p>
                </div> -->
        </div>
        <!-- скрины треков -->
        <div class="cards">
            <div onclick="gruppy()" ondblclick="pausesong1()">
                <img src="img/track_list/gruppy.jpg" alt="">
                <div class="name_container">
                    <div class="track">Групи</div>
                    <div class="artist">Платина & OG Buda</div>
                </div>
                <div class="progress_bar">
                </div>
                <div class="time_bar">
                    <div class="start_track">0:00</div>
                    <div class="end_track">3:11</div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel_players">
                    <div class="left_button">
                        <img src="img/button/left.png" alt="left">
                    </div>
                    <div class="play_button">
                        <img src="img/button/play.png" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="rigth_button">
                        <img src="img/button/right.png" alt="">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel_volume">
                    <input type="range" min='0 'max="100" >
                </div>
                <div class="volume_regulator">
                    <img class='left_vol' src="img/button/volume-mute.png" alt="">
                    <img class='rigth_volume' src="img/button/volume-up.png" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>





            <div onclick="kak_v_perviy_raz()" ondblclick="pausesong2()">
                <img src="img/track_list/kak_v_perviy_raz.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div onclick="lambo()" ondblclick="pausesong3()">
                <img src="img/track_list/lambo.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div>
                <img src="img/track_list/valentina.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div>
                <img src="img/track_list/navsegda.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div>
                <img src="img/track_list/diana.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div>
                <img src="img/track_list/salam_jpg.jpg" alt="">
            </div> 
            <div>
                <img src="img/track_list/big_boy.jpg" alt="">
            </div>

        </div>

        <!-- второй блок -->

    </div>
    
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: попробовал по перенести еще раз свойство, вроде бы кнопки хорошо встают(приблизительно хорошо), а вот текст улетает

Comment: еще бы понять, как загружать, чтобы картинки были все видны, а то я скидываю код, а что-там происходит один я вижу